# config.ConfigException$Missing: No configuration setting found for key 'dev' -- scala

Tags: java, scala, bigdata

I was trying some simple db operation using Scala. Where my code is connecting to mysql server.

I have define the DB details in application.properties file, but while running I am getting this error

```
config.ConfigException$Missing: No configuration setting found for key 'dev'
```

I checked all possible option but could find what is the issue, Can anyone help me on this ?

```
parsedConfig = ConfigFactory.parseFile(new File("src/main/resources/application.properties"))
    val prop = ConfigFactory.load(parsedConfig)
    val driver = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
    val url = s"jdbc:mysql://" + prop.getConfig("dev").getString("host") +
              "/" + prop.getConfig("dev").getString("db")
    val user = prop.getConfig("dev").getString("user")
    val password = prop.getConfig("dev").getString("pw")
```

**application.properties**

```
dev.host=localhost
dev.db=retail_db
dev.user=root
```

Comment: have you tried `prop.getConfig("dev.host")` ?

Comment: or maybe `prop.getConfigObject("dev").getConfig("host")`

Comment: yeah I tried dev.host, didnt work
there is no such getConfigObject in scala typesafe config

Answer (score 0):

To access a resource file in standard location with a standard name (i.e. "application.{properties|conf}") , it suffices to write:

```
val prop = ConfigFactory.load()
```

One reason why your config file is not found might be, that you have a multi-module project and try to access a config file in a sub-project. Then you have to prepend the directory name of the sub-project.

B.t.w. in general code should not access files in
src/main/resources as this directory will not exist when you run your compiled code outside the IDE, i.e. in production mode.

To see what files and directories will be in your final application, perform 'sbt compile' and then look at directory 'target/scala-2.12/classes'.